# using River tool to load a trained model

Tags: python

I have a trained model (Bi-LSTM) with h5 format and I want to use it to predict a value in my production ,
but I want to use River in order to predict value and trained the model  (update its weights)

I did this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from river import base, optim, metrics
from river.models.keras import Keras

# Load the Keras model
keras_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')

model = Keras(
    keras_model=keras_model,
    optimizer=optim.SGD(lr=0.1),
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    batch_size=32
)

river_model = base.Wrapper(model)
```

I get this error :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'river.wrappers' and ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'river.models'

Even though I installed the latest version of river

any way ,how can I load a trained model and use it in my production for predict values and train it of the same time (online learning)